# How to read properties file, which is in another package of a java project?

Tags: java, properties-file

I have created `config.properties` file in a separate package. Now I need to read this data from different Java package's class. please suggest the lines of code, such that the same need to be run by taking proper directories even if I run over cloud (Jenkins).

click here for image [1](https://i.stack.imgur.com/hk0O5.png)

Comment: Please post some code example and show some effort and basic knowledge

Comment: It must be on your classpath.

Comment: ...`java.lang.ClassLoader#getResourceAsStream("/absolute/path/to/resource")` returns an `java.io.InputStream` (,which you can pass to `java.util.Properties#load()`) ... when `/absolute/path/to/resource` is *available on the class path* (e.g./also in a .jar). Which class loader to take depends on the environment, but `Thread.currentThread().getContextClassLoader()` should be fail safe (in all environments).

Comment: so: `Properties props = new Properties(); props.load(Thread.currentThread().getContextClassLoader().getResourceAsStream("/com/cleartripqa/config/config.properties"));` could work (, when it's on the class path).

Answer (score 0):

It is better to put file to resources folder (src/main/resources) and use classloader to get it as mentioned above.